# Unable to get form data by tag name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get form data in jQuery, I have tried two following methods:

```
var form = document.getElementById('user_form');   //By using form id
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form');  //By form tag name
```

the first one gives me the result in the following format:

```
<form id="user_form" action="/users/create_user"  method="post">
// ...
</form>
```

which is ok, but when I try the second method then it returns me the result in the form of object.

```
[form#user_form, user_form: form#user_form]
```

but I am looking for the result in the same format which 1st method returns.

Comment: does this help: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ ?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList. Everything is working as it is supposed to here.

Comment: but i want the result in html format by using TagName

Comment: `document.querySelector("form")`

Comment: Neither of those gives you a result "in html format", that is nonsense. getElementById returns the reference to a single element node, whereas getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList. Neither of those are "in html format". (If you force them into a context that requires conversion into a string value, you might get different results. But that is something you would do for debugging purposes only, it makes no sense to do that in code that is actually supposed to perform some actions on those elements.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a list of nodes which satisties that tag name.
You can apply indexing to get a single element.

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');  //By form tag name
var form = forms[0];
```

Comment: That gives you the reference to the first form element in the document. This has nothing whatsoever to do with "getting the HTML".

Comment: @CBroe I agree that this has nothing whatsoever to do with "getting the HTML". It will just get the first element of form in the doc.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to make sure; the person asking the question seems to have a wrong understanding of what those methods actually do.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use jquery selector to access the node you want with just indexing. Here is an example with vanilla and jquery:

```
var htmlFormById = $("#user_form")[0];
console.log("htmlFormById",htmlFormById);
var htmlFormByTag = $("form")[0];
console.log("htmlFormByTag",htmlFormByTag);
var formById =  document.getElementById('user_form');
console.log(formById);
var formByTag = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
console.log(formByTag);
```

Here is a working solution in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/toc3ej6s/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var InnerHtml = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML 
InnerHtml = serialize(document.forms[0]);   //Serialized Form Data
```

Found That on this one [JavaScript Form serialized](https://www.formget.com/javascript-serialize/)

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified tag name

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')
```